# xlwings book open excel workbook but change the file name to lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlwings, capitalization

I used xlwings to open excel workbook. It worked fine up to last month. But today, when I run the same code, it opened my worksheet but convert my worksheet name into lowercase.

Anybody know why is that? And how can I keep my original captalization?

I am using windows 10.

Example, when I run below code, the ABC.xlsx automatically converted abc.xlsx by xlwings.

```
import xlwings as xw

fullPath = ''\\\\xxx\\xxx\\ABC.xlsx'
psw = '123'
wb = xw.Book(fullPath, password = psw)
```

Comment: Are you saying that **wb.fullname** shows the excel name as lowercase or somewhere else? Are you sure that the filename is uppercase? In Windows the fullpath variable using uppercase will open the file if the name is ABC.xlsx or abc.xlsx or any other capitalisation combination. If you need to refer to the filename in uppercase in the code you could use python upper().

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I am not sure why it does that (I think it only happens to protected workbooks). An easy fix is renaming the file again as follows:

```
import os
old_file_name = os.path.split(fullPath)[0] +'\\' + os.path.split(fullPath)[1].lower() 
new_file_name = fullPath
os.rename(old_file_name, new_file_name)
```

This code assumes that your path and file are saved under fullPath.